# File size in assembly

Tags: file, assembly, tasm

I have a following code written in TASM assembly for reading from a file and printing out the file content using a buffer.

Buffer declaration:

```
buffer         db 100 dup (?), '$'   ;regarding to comment, buffer is db 101 dup (?), '$'
```

**EDIT**

The structure of my program is:

Task 1 is asking me for a file name (string) which I want to read. 
After I input file name, the procedure `task1` opens the file.

```
mov ah, 3dh
xor al, al 
lea dx, fname
int 21h                         ;open file
jc openError                    
mov bx, ax
```

*Not sure, if opening the file is correct, because I have seen similar ways of opening the file but I do not have a handler here, or?*

Here is the reading part `task2`:

```
task2       proc
            pam 10,13                       ;pam is macro for printing out               

read:
            mov ah, 3fh
            lea dx, buffer
            mov cx, 100 
            int 21h
            jc readError                    ;read error , jump
            mov si, ax
            mov buffer[si], '$'
            mov ah, 09h
            int 21h                         ;print out 
            cmp si, 100
            je read
            jmp stop                        ;end
openError:
            pam error1
            jmp stop
readError:
            pam error2

stop:       ret
task2       endp
```

My question is, how can I get file length using this code? I have read that there are some ways of getting file size but they all look very complicated and I was thinking that when I read file, I should be able to calculate file size by storing number of characters I read in a register but I am not so sure about it and if it is possible, then I have no idea how to do that in tasm. Also in data segment, what variable do I need for storing file size? Maybe a code snippet would help me understand the process with some helpful comments how does it work. Thanks for help.

**UPDATE regarding to the answer:**

So I tried to convert hexa to decimal, it kinda works but I must have some bug in there because it works for small file, lets say I tried 1kB file and it worked, I got size in Bytes printed out on screen but when I tried bigger file like 128kB, decimal numbers were not correct - printed size was wrong, file is big exactly `130,862 bytes` and my conversion gave me `-- MENU653261 = Enter file name`.

```
... code from the answer ...
lea     di,[buffer]     ; hexa number will be written to buffer
mov     word ptr [di],('0' + 'x'*256)  ; with C-like "0x" prefix
add     di,2            ; "0x" written at start of buffer
mov     ax,dx
call    AxTo04Hex       ; upper word converted to hexa string
mov     ax,cx
call    AxTo04Hex       ; lower word converted to hexa string
mov     byte ptr [di],'$'   ; string terminator

;HEX TO DECIMAL = my code starts here
    mov cx,0
    mov bx,10

loop1: mov dx,0
    div bx
    add dl,30h
    push dx
    inc cx
    cmp ax,9
    jg loop1

    add al,30h
    mov [si],al

loop2: pop ax
    inc si
    mov [si],al
    loop loop2

    ; output final string to screen
    mov     ah,9
    lea     dx,[buffer]
    int     21h
```

Here is a screen how it looks when the decimal value gets printed out. It is mixed with the next line. I tried to move it to the next line but did not help. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSyYb.png)

Comment: You *can* calculate file size by reading its content and counting, but it's very ineffective. By using some kind of `sys_stat` call you can read different information about file without reading it's full content (faster). The correct type to store size depends on the file system used, for common modern file systems 64 bit is minimum, so `long long` in C/C++, or `qword` in TASM. From your source it looks like DOS assembly, for DOS FAT FS 32bit is enough (DOS does not support files over 4GiB size, and many tools fail already for 2+GiB files).

Comment: Actually in DOS there's one more way, if you don't want to go into "FCB" file services, and want to stay with the "handle" variants, you can get length of file by [setting the file pointer](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-42.html) to the end of file, and reading the returned value.

Comment: @Ped7g I need to read files only about 1Mb so big files are not a problem. It's only some kind of school assignment. And yes I am working with DOS 32bit. So you are suggesting to use sys_stat?

Comment: yes, but I didn't find `sys_stat`-like service in `int 21h` description, I think most of it is implemented by reading the directory "file" content, so that would be quite some code. If you want only length, use the file pointer trick (link above to the service description, params al=2, cx:dx=0, dx:ax will be length of file (verify in debugger I understood the service description correctly and it works :) )). That should be just few (~10) instructions. About max file size, if you can display it in hex then correct uint32 is easy. In dec it may be a bit tricky in 16b asm, but you can google...

Comment: BTW your current code is overwriting memory, you need 101 bytes buffer, if you put `'$'` after 100 bytes read.

Comment: It's a bit confusing since it's my first time with assembly, but basicaly I can create a procedure which is completly independent - no other procedure required to get file length using the file pointer? And the code in the link provided, could you guide me a bit how to use it and apply? Thanks

Comment: you can write independent procedure, it will need only opened file handle as input (you do open the file by `int 21h, ah=3Dh` at the beginning, receiving the "file handle"). But to make that independent procedure truly without side effects you would have to first read current file pointer, set it to the end (reading file length), and restore it back to old position. If you will use just the "set to end" part, and you will call such procedure before reading your buffer, nothing will be read (EOF reached).

Comment: At link: it's not code, is API description, how to call it. Check other `int 21h` services, for example the `3Dh` you are using to [open file](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-3d.html) and compare it with your current code, how it describes what you have to set before the `int 21h` call instruction, and how you treat the values which are returned. Use the other description in the same way. Ask if you run into particular problem.

Comment: I have updated some code and added a question also. I am going to open the file at first, then I can read it or if I want to get file length, I can use file handler from the `task1`, correct? Well if so, I need to know where is that handler, cause it is not clear for me yet.

Comment: Compare your "task 1" code with http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-3d.html (open file DOS service description), focus on the part after `int 21h`. Do you see `jc openError`? That's conditional jump, if CF is set, it will jump to the `openError:` label, otherwise it will continue with next instruction. Check that docs, what does it say: *"on return: AX = error code if CF set"*. If CF=0, then next `mov bx,ax` is executed. Check the description to see what is `ax`: *"on return: AX = file handle if CF is not set"* ... so there you go, the `int 21h` will return with file handle in `ax`, if CF=0.

Comment: I do not understand the `CX` `DX` `high\low order word` part and also in condition the part with `DX:AX = new ptr location...`

Comment: File pointer is 32 bit number. Those registers are 16 bits. You need two 16b registers to store 32 bit number. "low" are bits b0-b15, "high" are bits b16-b31. Then `dx:ax` is `dx` being high, `ax` being low word of the full 32b value. If dx=0x1234 and ax=0x5678, then `dx:ax` is `0x12345678`. For set it is the `cx:dx` pair forming 32b value to set. (in combination with "2" to end you want end + 0, so clear both cx and dx to have 32 bit zero value in them). It's same as `ax=0x1234 => ah=0x12, al=0x34` and `ah:al = ax`, these ah/al even have high/low in their name, but relates to "byte in word".

Comment: Also for example the `div r/m16` works with `dx:ax` 32b input, ie. `div bx` calculates `ax = dx:ax / bx`. "low" with bits/bytes means values toward zeroth power of two (value 1), and "high" means values toward the maximum power of two (31th power for highest bit in 32 bit number). Another example: if you name individual bits from b0 to b31, then value of bit itself is power(2, N) where N is the number from bit name bN. In binary number `101` the first 1 has value 2\*\*2 = 4, second/last 1 has value 2\*\*0 = 1 => `0b101 = 4 + 1 = 5`.  (2\*\*N = power(2, N))

Comment: Thanks. So now I get what the high and low words are but in the assembly syntax Im quite out of the track I guess. I have added some code on the end what I tried to get the size and print it out in Bytes  I hope it is but I dont think its correct.

Comment: No, there's so much confusion, that you should simply start by some assembly course/tutorial, from the start. It looks like you don't even get what registers are. Also DOS has no service to print number (not even 16b), the ah=9 expects pointer to "$" terminated string. So to print length of file you would have to convert that `dx:ax` value into string with digits, ending with "$", and that alone (to convert 32b value into decimal string in 16b real mode) is far from trivial task, I personally wouldn't bother, I would print it as hexa for myself, which is "simple" (about ~10-20 lines of code)).

Comment: I am reading a tutorial to understand the basics but it needs some practise of course. I do understand registers basics but some things are just not easy to process at first. Btw, since I read my file and then print it out, total number of bytes I read (in one loop?) is stored in register `ax` (if I am right). Why can't I just use this number of bytes and get my total file length?

Comment: You read the file in loop by 100 byte length segments. If your file is under 100B long, the returned `ax` "read bytes" is directly length of file. If you will reserve some register/memory as length counter (init to 0), and you will add returned `ax` to it in every loop, you will get correct file length for files of 0 to 65535 (0xFFFF) bytes. Of longer files the 16 bit register/memory will overflow upon next `add`, so you need to either reserve two registers or 32bit memory. And do composed adding, adding low word first with `ADD`, then high word with `ADC` with the CF being set by `ADD`.

Comment: Again to display that number you need separate conversion routine turning number value into decimal/hexa string, and outputting that string by ah=9,int 21h DOS service. For the moment I would not worry about that, instead I would use debugger, and read+verify the resulting value by reading the content of register/memory in debugger, not outputting anything to screen. (overall you should spend some time in debugger stepping over instructions of examples, and watching how registers/memory content does change, it's nice visual help to understand how CPU works)

Comment: For my assignment, I should be able to work with files without any problems up to 128kB. So if I do two 16bit registers, I should be okay with register memory, correct? If so, how do I reserve 2 registers so nothing else will use them? And the printing part, I will search more about it and if I find nothing, I will ask soon in new topic. I gotta get it done by sunday, also with finding all numbers in the file, printing them out and write total number of numbers found. I am looking forward for your help. Thank you

Comment: How do you reserve registers = you can't, you have to know which code is being called, and to know, that it can be trusted to not modify them. `int 21h` does preserve all registers except the ones being stated in documentation to change (`ax` is usually always changed). Your routines = you can tell, what they modify. Others routines = either they follow some calling convention, which lists what registers may be changed/preserved, or they are documented, or expect anything and save values yourself into memory or stack.

Comment: What do you mean by finding all number in the file, every file consists of numbers only :) (each byte of file can be seen as 0-255 numeric value). If you mean a text file: so number is only consecutive '0'-'9' ASCII characters? Then you should define how precise it should be for unexpected file content, like "dFr23.3a\ns5e3" = are those numbers? Two (2xdecimal w/ scientific notation)? Three (decimal, int, int)? Four (23, 3, 5, 3)? For a learning task I think a well defined and commented "garbage in, garbage out" solution will be accepted, but show that you gave it a thorough thought.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about text file with regular numbers 0-9. Since I have no idea how this can be acheived, I do not know how difficult would it be to deal also with decimals and other crazy content. If its too difficult, lets just say I want to be able to find number by itself eg. text .. 342 .. and also number connected with some text eg. solution13 gives me only number 13, and also if possible, when the number starts with 0, eg. 0244 then print the entire number, no need to remove 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple code to display hexa-formatted length of DOS file (file name is hardcoded in source, edit it to existing file):

```lisp
.model small
.stack 100h

.data

fname    DB "somefile.ext", 0
buffer   DB 100 dup (?), '$'

.code

start:
    ; set up "ds" to point to data segment
    mov     ax,@data
    mov     ds,ax
    ; open file first, to get "file handle"
    mov     ax,3D00h        ; ah = 3Dh (open file), al = 0 (read only mode)
    lea     dx,[fname]      ; ds:dx = pointer to zero terminated file name string
    int     21h             ; call DOS service
    jc      fileError
    ; ax = file handle (16b number)

    ; now set the DOS internal "file pointer" to the end of opened file
    mov     bx,ax           ; store "file handle" into bx
    mov     ax,4202h        ; ah = 42h, al = 2 (END + cx:dx offset)
    xor     cx,cx           ; cx = 0
    xor     dx,dx           ; dx = 0 (cx:dx = +0 offset)
    int     21h             ; will set the file pointer to end of file, returns dx:ax
    jc      fileError       ; something went wrong, just exit
    ; here dx:ax contains length of file (32b number)

    ; close the file, as we will not need it any more
    mov     cx,ax           ; store lower word of length into cx for the moment
    mov     ah,3Eh          ; ah = 3E (close file), bx is still file handle
    int     21h             ; close the file
    ; ignoring any error during closing, so not testing CF here

    ; BTW, int 21h modifies only the registers specified in documentation
    ; that's why keeping length in dx:cx registers is enough, avoiding memory/stack

    ; display dx:cx file length in hexa formatting to screen
    ; (note: yes, I used dx:cx for storage, not cx:dx as offset for 42h service)
    ; (note2: hexa formatting, because it's much easier to implement than decimal)
    lea     di,[buffer]     ; hexa number will be written to buffer
    mov     word ptr [di],('0' + 'x'*256)  ; with C-like "0x" prefix
    add     di,2            ; "0x" written at start of buffer
    mov     ax,dx
    call    AxTo04Hex       ; upper word converted to hexa string
    mov     ax,cx
    call    AxTo04Hex       ; lower word converted to hexa string
    mov     byte ptr [di],'$'   ; string terminator

    ; output final string to screen
    mov     ah,9
    lea     dx,[buffer]
    int     21h

    ; exit to DOS with exit code 0 (OK)
    mov     ax,4C00h
    int     21h

fileError:
    mov     ax,4C01h        ; exit with code 1 (error happened)
    int     21h

AxTo04Hex:  ; subroutine to convert ax into four ASCII hexadecimal digits
    ; input: ax = 16b value to convert, ds:di = buffer to write characters into
    ; modifies: di += 4 (points beyond the converted four chars)
    push    cx              ; save original cx to preserve it's value
    mov     cx,4
AxTo04Hex_singleDigitLoop:
    rol     ax,4            ; rotate whole ax content by 4 bits "up" (ABCD -> BCDA)
    push    ax
    and     al,0Fh          ; keep only lowest nibble (4 bits) value (0-15)
    add     al,'0'          ; convert it to ASCII: '0' to '9' and 6 following chars
    cmp     al,'9'          ; if result is '0' to '9', just store it, otherwise fix
    jbe     AxTo04Hex_notLetter
    add     al,'A'-(10+'0') ; fix value 10+'0' into 10+'A'-10 (10-15 => 'A' to 'F')
AxTo04Hex_notLetter:
    mov     [di],al         ; write ASCII hexa digit (0-F) to buffer
    inc     di
    pop     ax              ; restore other bits of ax back for next loop
    dec     cx              ; repeat for all four nibbles
    jnz     AxTo04Hex_singleDigitLoop
    pop     cx              ; restore original cx value back
    ret                     ; ax is actually back to it's input value here :)
end start
```

I tried to comment the code extensively, and to use "more straightforward" implementation of this stuff, avoiding some less common instructions, and keep the logic simple, so actually you should be able to comprehend how it works fully.

Again I strongly advise you to use debugger and go instruction by instruction slowly over it, watching how CPU state is changing, and how it correlates with my comments (note I'm trying to comment not what the instruction exactly does, as that can be found in instruction reference guide, but I'm trying to comment my human intention, why I wrote it there - in case of some mistake this gives you idea what should have been the correct output of the wrong code, and how to fix it. If comments just say what the instruction does, then you can't tell how it should be fixed).

Now if you would implement 32b_number_to_decimal_ascii formatting function, you can replace the last part of this example to get length in decimal, but that's too tricky for me to write from head, without proper debugging and testing.

Probably the simplest way which is reasonably to implement by somebody new to asm is to have table with 32b divisors for each 32b decimal digit and then do nested loop for each digits (probably skipping storage of leading zeroes, or just incrementing the pointer before printing to skip over them, that's even less complex logic of code).

Something like (pseudo code similar to C, hopefully showing the idea):

```
divisors  dd 1000000000, 100000000, 10000000, ... 10, 1

for (i = 0; i < divisors.length; ++i) {
    buffer[i] = '0';
    while (divisors[i] <= number) {
        number -= divisors[i];
        ++digit[i];
    }
}
digit[i] = '$';
// then printing as
ptr_to_print = buffer;
// eat leading zeroes
while ( '0' == ptr_to_print[0] ) ++ptr_to_print;
// but keep at least one zero, if the number itself was zero
if ('$' == ptr_to_print[0] ) --ptr_to_print;
print_it   // dx = ptr_to_print, ah = 9, int 21h
```

And if you wonder, how do you subtract 32 bit numbers in 16 bit assembly, that's actually not that difficult (as 32b division):

```
; dx:ax = 32b number
; ds:si = pointer to memory to other 32b number (mov si,offset divisors)
sub   ax,[si]    ; subtract lower word, CF works as "borrow" flag
sbb   dx,[si+2]  ; subtract high word, using the "borrow" of SUB
; optionally: jc overflow
   ; you can do that "while (divisors[i] <= number)" above
   ; by subtracting first, and when overflow -> exit while plus
   ; add the divisor back (add + adc) (to restore "number")
```

---

Points to question update:

You don't convert hex to decimal (hex string is stored in `buffer`, you don't load anything from there). You convert value in ax to decimal. The `ax` contains low word of file length from previous hex conversion call. So for files of length up to 65535 (0xFFFF = maximum 16b unsigned integer) it may work. For longer files it will not, as upper word is in `dx`, which you just destroy by `mov dx,0`.

If you would actually keep `dx` as is, you would divide file length by `10`, but for file with 655360+ length it would crash on divide error (overflow of quotient). As I wrote in my answer above, doing 32b / 16b division on 8086 is not trivial, and I'm not even sure what is the efficient way. I gave you hint about using table of 32b divisors, and doing the division by subtraction, but you went for `DIV` instead. That would need some sophisticated split of the original 32b value into smaller parts up to a point where you can use `div bx=10` to extract particular digits. Like doing filelength/1e5 first, then calculate 32b remainder (0..99999) value, which can be actually divided by 10 even in 16b (99999/10 = 9999 (fits 16b), remainder 9).

Looks like you didn't understand why 128k file length needs 32 bits to store, and what are the effective ranges of various types of variables. 2<sup>16</sup> = 65536 (= 64ki) ... that how big your integers can get, before you run into problems. 128ki is two times over that => 16 bit is problem.

Funny thing... as you wrote "converting from hex to decimal", at first I though: what, you convert that hexa string into decimal string??? But actually that sounds doable with 16b math, to go through whole hexa number first picking up only 10<sup>0</sup> values (extracted from particular k*16<sup>n</sup> value), then in next iteration doing 10<sup>1</sup> counting, etc...

But that division by subtracting 32bit numbers from my previous answer should be much easier to do, and especially to comprehend, how it works.

You write the decimal string at address `si`, but I don't see how you set `si`, so it's probably pointing into your MENU string by accident, and you overwrite that memory (again using debugger, checking `ds:si` values to see what address is used, and using memory view to watch the memory content written would give you hint, what is the problem).

Basically you wasted many hours by not following my advices (learning debugging and understanding what I meant by 32b - 32b loop doing division), trying to copy some finished code from Internet. At least it looks like you can somewhat better connect it to your own code, but you are still missing obvious problems, like not setting `si` to point to destination for decimal string.

Maybe try to first to print all numbers from the file, and keep the size in hexa (at least try to figure out, why conversion to hexa is easy, and to decimal not). So you will have most of the task done, then you can play with the hardest part (32b to decimal in 16b asm).

BTW, just a day ago or so somebody had problem with doing addition/subtraction over 64b numbers in 16b assembly, so this answer may give you further hints, why doing those conversion by sub/add loops is not that bad idea, it's quite "simple" code if you get the idea how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42645266/4271923

Comment: That 32b value to string routine suggestion is probably very inefficient when compared to some pro solution (if you have 16b clib from some 16b C/C++ compiler, you may try to reverse engineer it's `sprintf` implementation to see how it converts 32b integer), so this is not something to be used for real, where performance matters, it's designed to be reasonably simple to implement, not to be fast. Still for printing length of file once it will be surely fast enough. :D (but printing million numbers with it may take some time).

Comment: Dude, I will be happy with the simplest code which can be slow, I do not care :D I have to finish 3 other projects in 2 weeks so I just need to get rid of this one because its totally out of my profile :D But back to the code. I tried to create new file with your code, had to use `ds` instead of `@data` for reading the data segment, then there is a missing `:` by `AxTo04Hex_singleDigitLoop` and thats it. And when I run the program, it only gives me two empty lines and third one is `Program executed succesfully.` Thats it.

Comment: And also, how would this code change, if the filename had to be set by user? So I can set the name as user input...Because that's what I have now and my opening procedure with file handler looks different and its a bit confusing.

Comment: About `ds`: not sure what you did, do you use TASM to compile? I will try to fix it as complete .exe example ready to compile with TASM. If you already have input filename by user, you should sort of understand which part does that, where the filename is stored, etc... So you should be able to connect those two. :/ It sounds like you don't use debugger and you are unable to check yourself what is working wrong. That's very bad, you will probably not manage to finish the task, if you don't know to use debugger. If you have TASM, you probably have also TD (Turbo Debuuger). Spend 1-2h in it, NOW.

Comment: @Ady96 I finally understood the `ds` thing, I didn't notice the `dx` even after your comment, wow... blind leads blind. Anyway, I managed to get somebody with TASM, and verified that code works, just edit the filename to some file which is in the same directory as .exe, or put there full path like "F:\DOWNLOADS\ARCHIVEM~1.RAR" -> I tried with some 1GB file, and it did output the hexadecimal length of it. ... if it doesn't work for you, try TD and find why it doesn't reach the ending ah=9, int 21h, or what is printed there.

Comment: @Ady96 but if you did `mov ax,ds` instead of `mov ax,@data`, then you didn't fix it. The comment says "set ds", not read ds. Anyway, the source is now fixed and should work. If you name it for example "filelen.asm", then put that into the fname too, so it will report length of the asm source. Once it works, you can try to add user input. Also I tried turbo debugger under dosbox, and it works well with this exe.

Comment: I have updated my question with a part of your code followed by hex to decimal conversion.

Comment: Reacting to your edited answer. I started to think how should I do finding numbers, printing them out and print total count of numbers, I will need the decimal print function anyway to print them out, or not? Not sure if its possible way to do it, but if I check every byte when reading the file and the character is a number then I print it as decimal, because its not gonna be bigger then 9, right? And to make those numbers separated, I will need two registers one for storing actual reading byte and one for storing last byte read so I know if it is the end of the number or not, correct?

Comment: @Ady96 you are searching text, printing out text... except counting you don't even need to know what was that number you copied from in-stream to out-stream, all you need is to detect the beginning of number to turn copying ON (and increment counter), and end of number to switch copying OFF... and read the file from start to EOF. For counter of numbers (here for 128k is 16b enough, because at most every second char is digit = 64k numbers, but still you should probably count 32b with `add+adc` pair) start with that hexa output. After it works, look into decimals again.

Comment: What you posted in comment is good as first idea... you have to put that down into file as comments, and keep improving it, putting it against real input in head, until all steps are reasonably accurate and simple, and in your head it works for all basic inputs you can think of (either simple valid ones, or corner-case like empty file, no digits file, only digits file, etc). When you have working algorithm in comments, adding instructions to each step is usually not that hard. Don't rush to writing code, make sure all makes sense first. It may still prove to be wrong, but rushing is even worse

Comment: @Ady96 find me somewhere (fb + my nick as url for example)... I have some time, if I want, but you look to be too much fixed to "I will search a solution", which is annoying. "copying bytes" ... what is byte? What does `mov` do? You should take probably a step back a realize what those instructions are doing, it's heavy weaponry for all sort of basic calculations. The task you are solving is basically one bigger calculation where result is series of byte values sent to stdout (and input is series of bytes from stdin and from other file). You should be able to create that, at least for basics.