# How to subtract two 64 bit integers in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, dosbox

> Write a program called SUB64 to subtract the 64-bit integer in memory locations 0x0150 and 0x0154 from the 64-bit integer in 0x0160 and 0x0164. Store the result in memory location 0x0170 and 0x0174.

I understand the logic behind separating it into smaller pieces since we can't fit 64 bits into the registers. And I know we subtract the least significant pieces first. I'm struggling with actually coding it. Does it matter which GPIO we use? This is my example, so maybe you can see how I'm thinking. Maybe I'm not that far off, but it feels like it.

```
MOV AX, 0X0150
MOV BX, 0X0154
MOV CX, 0X0160
MOV DX, 0X0164
SUB BX, DX
SUB AX, CX
MOVE 0X0174, BX
MOVE 0X0170, AX
```

I stored each half of the 64 bit integer into the registers. Then I subtracted the registers and put them into the memory locations. Is that hex format okay? or does it need to be something like 0174h?

Even if this is somehow correct, do I need a return statement or a header or anything to make this actually compile? (I'm using NASM and DosBox)

This is the first of 12 similar programs I have to write. SO ANY push in the right direction will hopefully get me on my way!

Comment: You need to take care of the borrow from the low half to the high half - take a look at the `SBB` instruction.

Comment: thank you. can I simply store the value with the carry flag activated? or do I have to do something with these values so that when the data is read it returns the correct value? Sorry if this question doesnt make sense. If we have to put the 64 bit word back together, will the carry flag affect this, or will it all mesh together right?

Comment: Remember doing subtraction back in elementary school ? You would subtract a column at a time, and then "borrow" from the next column when needed ? Think of each half of the 64 bit value as a column. If you get a borrow from the first `SUB` then you need to propagate this to the high word subtraction, using the `SBB` instruction instead of `SUB`. Google for "x86 SBB" or similar and you should find tons of examples...

Comment: AX is a 16 bit register. You'll need to do one sub and 3 sbb's to perform a 64 bit subtract. A 64 bit integer needs 8 bytes or 4 words of data, That means that if the first (least significant) word of a 64 bit integer is located at 0x150, then the last (most significant) word is located at 0x156.

Comment: @Penrose5833 Both your problem description, and your code, reveal that you're still struggling with register sizes (eax 32 bit, ax 16 bit) and adressing modes ( `mov ax, 0x0150` vs `mov ax, [0x0150]` ) Perhaps these things are something worth looking up. Also 8086 is very old fashioned (still valid tho), but if you can - and are allowed to - you should use 32 bit assembly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)

> *the 64-bit integer in memory locations 0x0150 and 0x154*

that's not very exact task description, the 64b integer is in memory at locations from 0x0150 to 0x0157 (8 bytes in total). That description sounds like by default a memory unit `dword` (32 bits) is used, which in 16b real mode is not very sensible default data size.

2) `mov ax,0x0150` does not load the value from memory, it loads that constant `0x0150` into `ax`. If you want to load the actual value from memory, you have to dereference that memory address, like for example:

```
mov si,0x0150  ; set si to contain address of input number1
mov ax,[si]    ; load least significant 16b word (LSW) of it into ax

; you can even use absolute addressing like:
mov  ax,[0x0150]  ; usually not practical, but possible
```

Now if you would want to put all addresses of all words (3 * 4 words of memory will be used, num1, num2 and result, all of them 4 words long), you would run out of registers quickly. But actually you can use relative addressing in 16b mode, so this is possible:

```
mov   si,0x0150  ; set si to contain address of input number1
mov   ax,[si]
mov   bx,[si+2]
mov   cx,[si+4]
mov   dx,[si+6]
; here dx:cx:bx:ax concatenated into single 64b number contains the number1
```

But the number2 can be addressed by base address of number1 too, so you can also continue by subtraction:

```
sub   ax,[si+0x10]   ; subtraction of LSW, ignoring CF (borrow)
sbb   bx,[si+0x12]   ; continuing by subtracting adjoining 16 bits
    ; but this time CF will affect the result, to make any "borrowing"
    ; happening while subtracting the LSW to propagate into upper 16 bits
... etc..
```

About your question in comments... the result modified by CF is already stored in `bx`, the old CF is lost, CF contains new "borrow" of `bx - [0x162] - old_borrow`. You *can* store CF somewhere if you wish, the CPU has instructions to detect/store/set value of CF, but with numbers once you calculate 15 - 8 is 7, the 7 is final, you don't need to remember you did borrow the "1" to subtract 8 from 5.

And the result address is again easy to calculate relatively to num1 address, so you can just store the result back into memory

```
mov   [si+0x20],ax  ; 0x0150 + 0x20 = 0x0170
mov   [si+0x22],bx
...
```

And I basically gave you whole solution :/ ... so let's add some more info at least, to make you work it out a bit.

You can do the same without using 4 16b registers to hold the single 64b value, like:

```
mov   ax,[si]
sub   ax,[si+0x10]
mov   [si+0x20],ax
mov   ax,[si+2]
sbb   ax,[si+0x10+2]
mov   [si+0x20+2],ax
...
```

After looking at that one, you may get a great idea, how about:

```
mov   ax,[si]
sub   ax,[si+0x10]
mov   [si+0x20],ax
add   si,2          ; adjust rather base pointer then changing all those offsets
mov   ax,[si]
sbb   ax,[si+0x10]
mov   [si+0x20],ax
...
```

Does it work? Not any more. The `add si,2` will modify the CF, so the next `sbb` does not "continue" in the subtraction. The lesson to learn here is, that you should often check instruction reference guide for detailed ins. description, including which flags it does affect. With x86 - some instruction can surprise you, for example the code above modified to:

```
mov   ax,[si]
sub   ax,[si+0x10]
mov   [si+0x20],ax
inc   si        ; adjust base pointer
inc   si
mov   ax,[si]
sbb   ax,[si+0x10]
mov   [si+0x20],ax
...
```

WILL work, because `inc` does NOT affect CF, only other arithmetic flags are modified.

Another way to add two to valid addressing register without modifying any flag is `lea si,[si+2]`.

BTW dosbox by default emulates 386+, so you can use even in 16b real mode:

```
mov   si,0x0150
mov   eax,[si]
mov   ebx,[si+4]    ; ebx:eax = 64b number1 (note +4 this time)
sub   eax,[si+0x10]
sbb   ebx,[si+0x14] ; ebx:eax = (number1 - number2)
mov   [si+0x20],eax
...
```

Unless you were constrained to use only 8086 (80286) instruction sets, the 32 bit registers were introduced with 80386 CPU.

Comment: reading "divide 0x0150 and 0x154" ... "from 0x0160 and 0x164" i'd assume he is allowed to use 32 bit registers, (0x0170/4 = 0x0150/4 - 0x160/4 ). 0x0154 is the 2nd half of the first value, not the 2nd

Comment: @Tommylee2k probably yes, but he used only `ax` in his own code... Maybe he's not aware about the subtle difference between `eax`, `ax` and `al`, confusing them still? I did add example with 32b registers to the end of my answer. But it actually doesn't hurt if he can compare it with the pure 16b version, what/how needs to be adjusted when you are changing data types. :)

Comment: I think you're right, But imo your "btw:" part was the better answer, while your current answer could confuse him more than it's helping ;) But without knowing if they're developing 16bit or 32bit, we cannot really decide this. I know professors still teaching 8086 assembly with hex input into some kit

Comment: Thank you, this was a huge help. For some reason I am held to using only the intel 8086, and next week we switch to the ARM7.

Comment: "so let's add some more info at least, to make you work it out a bit." Good extra info by pointing out the pitfall of inadvertently modifying the CF flag!