# input and display 32 bit number without using multiply or division

Tags: assembly, binary, x86-16, emu8086

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data 
tempax dw ?
tempdx dw ?
num dw ?
.code

.startup
push '@'      ; initializing values
mov tempax,0
mov tempdx,0
mov num,0
mov cx,0
mov dx,0


read:     ; taking input
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov ah,0
cmp al,13
je disp
Mov ch, 0
sub al,48
mov cl,al
mov ax,0
mov ax,num

clc ;clearing flag as rcl shifts value of flag to lsb
rcl ax,1
rcl dx,1
mov tempax,ax ;          save value of once shifted                     register as we to use it ahead

mov tempdx,dx ;      user 2 register to         accommodate 32 bit number 

clc

rcl ax,1
rcl dx,1
clc

rcl ax,1
rcl dx,1
clc

add ax,tempax   ; adding once shifted register with thrice shifted register 
adc dx,tempdx ; tc of any carry
clc
add al,cl    ; now adding number taken from user to result. 
adc dl,0 ; again taking care of carry
mov num,ax ; saving ax to num 
jmp read

disp:
mov ax,num 

mov bx,0 ; bx is used to save the remainder 
add bx,48 


disp1:


clc
rcr dx,1
rcr ax,1
rcl bx,1 ;shifts value of carry flag to bx

cmp ax,tempax
je poppy ; to stop loop
mov tempax,ax ; saving once shifted register
mov tempdx,dx
clc

rcr dx,1
rcr ax,1
rcl bx,1

clc

rcr dx,1
rcr ax,1
rcl bx,1

clc
xchg tempax,ax  
sub ax,tempax ;    subtracting once shifted with 3 times shifted register 

xchg tempdx,dx
sub dx,tempdx

push bx ; as bits are shifted they are saved in bx abd then pushed to stack

jmp disp1


poppy:

pop dx 

cmp dx,'@'; end of stack check
je exit
sub dx,48  ;converting back to ascii
mov ah,02h
int 21h
jmp poppy


exit:
mov ah,04ch
mov al,0
int 21h
end
```

First I take the input from the user with an interrupt function 01h compare it with enter key(code for enter is 13) then I convert the ASCII value to its absolute value. if we left shift a number 3 times and add it to number left shifted once it is equivalent to number * ten .after that I add the number input by user.so 1,2 becomes 12.now if I want to display the input I have to take out each character by dividing them and sending it to stack.then use poppy function to display the number but it is displaying some gibberish characters.yes I tried adding and as well as subtracting 48 ie converting to ASCII. This program runs with no syntax error there is a logical error which i cant find

Comment: Kudos for facing this task one step at a time. However, your code is really hard to understand because it lacks structure and comments, and some instructions seem useless.  Due to these, It's hard to mentally trace the execution and spot the bug. FWIW: division is not distributive in the divisor: x/10 is not x/(8 + 2)

Comment: I am using bit operations on binary. Multiplication is correct I checked that but problem is with displaying those characters  back. I think the bits i am saving as remainder. I have to convert them to some format. As i am shifting then bit by bit idk what the proper statndard is for representing a number in ascii ie how many bits signify a number. I just put 3 bits from shift and add 48 to it. I hope you getting my logic?

Comment: The text part of your question needs paragraphs.  It's short, but it's still really hard to read.  Is there some reason you need to convert to 32-bit binary, instead of keeping your number in multiple base-10 digits?  You can do carry manually between digits if you need to add or subtract.  The title question just asks about input and display...

Comment: If we divide a 32 bit number by 10 it store the quotient in AX and remainder in dx but if the number is big it doesn't saves half of the number. I tried that but not able to save results above 65536.ie highest number a 16 bit register can save

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42680822/4271923 - how you can avoid `div 10` with 32b values (by having table of powers of 10, and doing subtraction). This works quite OK for number display, generic 32b division with 16b code is more tricky, and I'm not even sure what is common approach, I have idea about 2-3 possibilities, but all are quite complex. But extracting the digits with 32b `sub` is quite simple to understand, and should be reasonable to write + debug.

Comment: @Guff 16bit register max capacity is 65535 not 65536 its from zero to 65535 which is indeed 65536.